# Why is it entering the loop? vb net mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I m new to vb net

So here is my problem

My database has 1 table=quiz and 3 columns of ID ,name and Flag
All flags are set to '0'
Whenever I delete ,instead of deleting ,I update the name field to xxx and Flag to 1

In my database ,ID =3 has name = xxx
Still y is it entering the loop? and printing the msg"OH no"?

my code :

```vb
Dim SQL as String
SQL = "SELECT Name FROM quiz WHERE  Flag='0' AND ID='3'"
            c = 0


            If SQL <> "xxx"Then
                ' Try, Catch, Finally


                i = i + 1
                MsgBox("Ohh no")
             END IF
```

Comment: There seems to be some missing code here (even after I corrected your formatting), since you never seem to actually *execute* your SQL.

Comment: Exactly, in your example, it should open a message box with "Ohh no", because the variable named SQL is in fact not equal to xxx.

Comment: What should i compare it with.....to not make it not enter the loop??

Comment: Which loop? There is no such thing in that code